# How to achieve movement between discount levels evaluated over a two year time period rather than 1?

Tags: r, statistics, poisson

The code below works so that the movement between the discount levels is evaluated yearly. e.g no claims made in 1 year, move up discount level, claim made in next year, move down a discount level,2 or more claims made in the year, drop back to 0% level of discount, and this is done according to a claim rates 0.1,...,0.8. If we were to now change the time period to two years. e.g if no claims were made in year 1 or year 2, move up a discount level, now if 1 claim is made in year 1 or year 2, move back down a discount level, or if 2 or more claims were made over the two year period, drop to the 0% level of discount. How can i edit this code to change the time period?

```
a <- array(0:0,dim=c(21,5000)) # over time period t=21, 5000 policy holders
d<-array(1:5) 
e<-array(1:5) # five discount levels used
p<-array(1:8) # premium charged for 8 separate claim rates
z=0
e[1]=1 # discount 0%
e[2]=.8 # discount 20%
e[3]=.7 # discount 30%
e[4]=.6 # discount 40%
e[5]=.5 # discount 50%

for (l in seq(0.1,0.8,.1)){ # claim rates 0.1,0.2,0.3...0.8
  for (j in 1:20){
    for (i in 1:5000) {
      b<-min(2,rpois(1,l))
      if (b==2) {a[j+1,i]=0}     # b is the number of claims made, if 2 or more, drop down to 0%discount
      if (b==1) {a[j+1,i]=max(0,a[j,i]-1)} # if 1 claim made, drop back one discount level
      if (b==0) {a[j+1,i]=min(4,a[j,i]+1)} # if 0 claims made, go to next level of discount
    }
  }    
  for (k in 1:5){
    d[k]=1000*e[k]*(length(subset(a[21,],a[21,]==(k-1)))/5000)
  }
  z=z+1;p[z]=sum(d)
}
p
```

Answer (score 1):

You really just need hold the previous value in memory and add it to your 'if' statements and flip your 'i' and 'j' loops.  This could look something like this:

```
for (i in 1:5000) {
  b_prev <- 0
  for (j in 1:20){    
    b<-min(2,rpois(1,l))
    if (b + b_prev >=2) {a[j+1,i]=0}     # b is the number of claims made, if 2 or more, drop down to 0%discount
    if (b + b_prev ==1) {a[j+1,i]=max(0,a[j,i]-1)} # if 1 claim made, drop back one discount level
    if (b + b_prev ==0) {a[j+1,i]=min(4,a[j,i]+1)} # if 0 claims made, go to next level of discount
    b_prev <- b
  }
}
```

What we're doing here is calculating all 20 years of a single policy holder, instead of calculating one year of all 5,000 policy holders.  Your math should work exactly the same, since you're using explicit references.  However, this rearranging of the loops allows us to use a lagging variable 'b_prev' to hold the last value of a year's claims and add it to the current years' claims when deciding how to reduce the discount level.  Notice, however, that 2 is no longer your max, since you can have two years with 2 claims for a max of 4.  I added a `>=` for the calculation that drops the discount back to zero.

Comment: So I want it to be calculated over a 21 year time period, but to have the transitions between discounts evaluated every 2 years.  And so if a policy holder makes 2 or more claims in the space of 2 years, they drop back to 0% discount, if the make 1 claim in either the first year or second year of the two years, then they drop back one level of discount etc. Is that what yourcode is doing?

Comment: I'm using your original code, except that I'm inverting the loops to complete one policy holder at a time, instead of doing it a year at a time with all policy holders.  Also, the evaluation currently happens each year and considers the past two years.  Year3 uses Year3 + Year2 claims, and Year4 uses Year4 + Year3 claims.  Were you intending instead to only evaluate on even years and never to adjust discounts on odd years?

Comment: Ok, I understand.  so then if you want to increase the decision rule to say a three or four year time period so say year3 now uses year 3 and year2 and year1, would you just increase the number of b_prevs and add them into your for loop? Is that how you would do it?

Comment: Sort of.  To quickly modify this code, I would just add in a 'b' array (`b<-integer(n_years)`) and then, I would shuffle the whole array down a level for each iteration (`b[1:(n_years-1)]<-b[2:n_years];b[n_years]<-min(2,rpois(1,l))`).  For each 'if' statement, I would use `sum(b) and just drop the 'b_prev' variable.  Something like that.

Comment: Do you know how I could modify this code so that every policy holder has the same past claims experience?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.  Could you be more specific?

Comment: I want to compare 1 year and 2 year exposure periods using a set of policy holders with the same claims experience. I was thinking of using 1 large for loop and use 2 new vectors to record the state history of each policy holder for both 1 year and 2 year exposure. But that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: You should probably start a new question for this.  All of these changes will make this question and its answer difficult to read for others.  If you have the answer you need for your original question, pick a "best" answer and then post your new question.  That will be most helpful to both you and others who later read the questions.